# Python Newline \n not working in jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to display the tuples of a postgreSQL table neatly in my Jupyter Notebook, but the newline \n escape character doesn't seem to work here (it works for my python scripts w/ same code outside of jupyter).

I'm trying to run:

```
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM Cars')
'\n '.join(str(x) for x in cur.fetchall())
```

But my output still contains the '\n' characters themselves:

```
"(1, 'Toyota', 'Supra', 2020, 'Sport', 'Gas', 49995.0, 7, 280.0, datetime.date(2020, 5, 27), 'Loan', 50150.0, 300.0, 987654321, 333356789)\n (4, 'Chevrolet', 'Corvette', 2020, 'Sport', 'Gas', 55999.0, 4, 280.0, datetime.date(2020, 5, 27), 'Loan', 58999.0, 300.0, 987444321, 333356789)\n (2, 'Toyota', '4Runner', 2018, 'Sport', 'Gas', 40599.0, 13266, 280.0, datetime.date(2020, 5, 27), 'Loan', 58999.0, 300.0, 987334321, 333356789)"
```

Any ideas as to what I need to do or add?

Comment: Are you printing the resulting string, or simply returning it? Returned strings on a console/Jupyter Notebooks always preserve their `\n` characters, instead of visually adding newlines.

Comment: Thank you, I just realized I need to print it for this to happen. I was just returning it, andI guess the raw string would just get displayed because of this. The print() on the other hand processes these escape characters

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you don't put the output in print statement. "\n" would be printed as "\n" instead of newline in jupyter notebook and python shell.

in: `'A\nB'`

out: `'A\nB'`

in: `print('A\nB')`

out:

```
A
B
```

The solution you need is:
`print('\n '.join(str(x) for x in cur.fetchall()))`

Answer (score 1):

For me, I was exporting my `.ipynb` file to `.pdf`, And because I was printing all my knowledge in one `print` line, it was cropped out in the PDF version.

The easiest solution is to use the **Triple Quotes**.

```py
# instead of
print("You're Strong, But I Could Snap My Fingers And\nYou'd All Cease To Exist.")

# use
print("""
You're Strong, But I Could Snap My Fingers And 
You'd All Cease To Exist.
"""
```

```
[Output]
Youre Strong, But I Could Snap My Fingers And
You'd All Cease To Exist.
```