# Adding a line break in string variable

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Here's my original string input from a csv

```
a = """"Asset Serial No;Depot"
"abc;111"""""
```

I want to remove the starting and ending double quotes, add opening and closing tag so it will be something like this:

```
<root>
Asset Serial No;Depot
abc;111
</root>
```

Here's my code:

```
b = "<root>" + "\n"
for line in a.splitlines():
    b = b + line.strip('""') + "\n"
    
b = b + "</root>"
```

But the resulting string looks like this

```
'<root>\nAsset Serial No;Depot\nabc;111\n</root>'
```

Any advise please?

UPDATE: Sorry, it turns out to be the display of Jupyter Notebook for me.

Comment: Your code works assuming you want that output when it is printed out

Comment: "But the resulting string looks like this" Okay; and how is that different from the result you want?

Comment: Anyway, closing tags in XML should look like `</root>` with a *forward* slash.

Comment: Sorry I was viewing the output on Jupyter Notebook. It's not showing "\n" as a new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code runs well for me.
"But the resulting string looks like this" -> what's the way you show the string?

```
a = """"Asset Serial No;Depot"
"abc;111"""""

b = "<root>" + "\n"
for line in a.splitlines():
    b = b + line.strip('""') + "\n"

b = b + "<root>"

print(b)
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, in Jupyter notebook it's not showing "\n" as a special character but as an actual string.

Comment: @anhtle This is a trivial problem. When you try to print it or write it into .txt, it is still ok: you will not see /n anymore. You can also refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62161001/python-newline-n-not-working-in-jupyter-notebooks. Hope it helps.

Comment: @anhtle Urw. Further, the reason why ```print``` and ``` write()``` can handle is because they are parsing the ```/n``` as a special character.